# Django is not populating correctly an specific form using a Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created two models Leads and Deals, and I have coded some logic such that if you click a button the Lead becomes a Deal, so what I want it is that a new form is presented to the user but that form already contains the information from the Leads model.

```
@login_required
def close_lead(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        deal_form = DealForm(request.POST)

        if deal_form.is_valid():
            deal_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
            id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
            obj = Leads.objects.get(project_id=id)
            obj.status = "Closed"
            obj.save(update_fields=['status'])

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')
    else:

        id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Leads, project_id=id)
        print(obj.expected_revenue)
        form = NewDealForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)


    return render(request,
                  "account/close_lead.html",
                  {'form':form})
```

I have done some debug and printed to the console the queryset and the information is fine, so the queryset is no the problem, the problem is that the NewForm doesn't prepopulate the new values.

models.py (only 2 models shown)

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
                ('Illumination Studies','Illumination Studies'),
                ('Training','Training'),
                ('Survey Design','Survey Design'),
                ('Software License','Software License')
               )
    STATUS = (('Open','Open'),
               ('Closed','Closed'),
               ('Canceled', 'Canceled')
              )
    project_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    point_of_contact = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expected_revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    expected_licenses = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS)
    estimated_closing_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company}'


class Deal(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='id')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='service')
    closing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='client')
    licenses = models.ForeignKey(Leads,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='licenses')
    revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Now, it could be that I have to inherit from a different form?

forms.py (only NewDealForm)

```
class NewDealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = ['agent','client','project_id','service', 'licenses','revenue', 'comments']
```

Obviously, worst-case scenario is to create a dictionary to extract the data from the queryset and then pass it to the form, but I'm sure Django has a more elegant way to handle this process.

Comment: Try to use `NewDealForm(request.POST or None, initial=obj.__dict__)`

Comment: @BrianD thanks, obviously that get's back a dictionary, but it does not populate the form, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess sometimes Stack Overflow pushes you to solve your own issues, this is the solution.

Essentially, the initial=queryset value was not initializing the form mainly because I have very specific relationships in  my model, so what I did is to create a dictionary (key:value) with the form field as key, and my queryset from my model as the value, the code is as below:

'''
def close_lead(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

```
    deal_form = DealForm(request.POST)

    if deal_form.is_valid():
        deal_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
        id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
        obj = Leads.objects.get(project_id=id)
        obj.status = "Closed"
        obj.save(update_fields=['status'])

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
    else:

        messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')
else:

    id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
    obj = get_object_or_404(Leads, project_id=id)

    m = obj.__dict__
    keys = Leads.objects.get(project_id=m['project_id'])

    form_dict = {'project_id':keys.project_id,
                 'agent':keys.agent,
                 'client':keys.point_of_contact,
                 'company':keys.company,
                 'service':keys.services
                 }
    form = NewDealForm(request.POST or None,initial = form_dict)


return render(request,
              "account/close_lead.html",
              {'form':form})
```

'''

As you can see, I create an object dictionary because the forms are different, so they share some common values not all, and then I simply adapt the dictionary, nice and easy, but I somehow expected that Django somehow finds relationships by name?, but maybe the batteries are not included for this.